# What is the argument against using before, let and subject in RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I just started writing RSpec tests, and I came across [thoughtbot's Style Guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/style), which recommends against `let`, `let!`, `before` and `subject` (among others).

I've also read similar suggestions in a few other places (including the old [RSpec docs](http://old.rspec.info/documentation/) warning about `before(:all)`), but I can't seem to find the actual argument against them.

So the question is:

*Why shouldn't I be using those methods in my tests? What is the better approach?*

Comment: This no longer appears in their style guide, presumably because let and subject are extremely useful.

Comment: @AlexNeth are you sure about that? I still see it here https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices but odly enough, let appears often in their very own factory_bot https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/search?q=let&unscoped_q=let

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Interesting question; something that I want to know more about as well.... So dug in a bit, and here is what I uncovered:

### Thoughtbot style guide dictum about `let`, etc.

1. In an [earlier version of the style guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/blob/40090e22f298c380a51b958cb9d6454e1cd4f700/README.md), there's more to that statement:

   *Avoid its, let, let!, specify, subject, and other DSLs. Prefer explicitness and consistency.*
2. ThoughtBot folks made a post on let name [let's not](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-not). See also the [link to the Github Commit Comment conversation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/commit/04b6e2ea8597ae46b24247b96da9b04645478fa0#commitcomment-1906596)
3. On one of their recent podcasts [Joe Ferris](https://github.com/jferris), the CTO of ThoughtBot, explains why it's not a good idea to use `let` and `subject`. Check out the podcast titled [Something Else Was Smellier](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/29134076552/something-else-was-smellier) from the 27m37s mark onwards for the next 5 minutes.
4. Testing Anti-pattern 'Mystery Guest' which is dealt with in detail in [an older ThoughtBot blogpost](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805321/mystery-guest) is the main reason for why not to use `let` and its cousins.

To summarize my understanding of all the above very succinctly:

> Using `let` et al makes it difficult to understand what's happening 
>   within the test on a quick glance, and requires the person to spend 
>   some time in making the connections.
>
> Write tests such that it is easy to understand without much effort.
>
> In addition, using `let` liberally in tests results in over-sharing among the tests, as well as makes implicit `common fixtures` - i.e. having a common fixture to start with for every test being written even when it does not apply.

### before(:all)

The argument against using `before(:all)` is straight-forward. As explained in the [old rspec documentation](http://old.rspec.info/documentation/):

> Warning: The use of before(:all) and after(:all) is generally discouraged because it introduces dependencies between the Examples. Still, it might prove useful for very expensive operations if you know what you are doing.

before(:all) gets executed only once at the start of the ExampleGroup. As such there is a potential to inadvertently introduce dependencies between the Examples. Thoughtbot's assertion about the tests not being easy to understand applies to this as well.

In conclusion, the advise for writing better specs seems to be:

1. Write tests such that they are easy to understand on a quick glance.
2. Know what you are doing.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the answer, I really appreciate the direction and guidance!

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts...

1. By using context, before, let, let! Test suit performs better (run faster)
2. By using this constructs one can create shared contexts using same idea of inheritance, so one can override what's needed on specific situations
3. The powerful shoulda matchers relies on subject in order to work
4. The rails specific type of specs (controller, model) relies on let, before and context behind the scene
5. Let is lazy load, it does not represent oversharing if is never referenced within specific tests, meaning that even if an it has access to 100 lets, but it only uses 1, the other 99 never gets computed at all
6. Is not only the test code what a developer have to read to understand the test suit, is also the output of the test suit when running, it gives a lot of sense to what is being tested
7. I agree on before(:all) obfuscates a lot of dependencies, but for performance reason I will use it if needed

Answer (score 1):

*Avoid its, let, let!, specify, before, and subject.*

Really? That cuts out the legs out from under the RSpec DSL. Might as well go back to using test/unit.

As to why they avoid `let`, Thoughtbot says: "We have a blog post coming out before too long that will hopefully explain." I'll wait with interest for those pearls of wisdom -- but in the meantime, take the style guide with a grain of salt.

*EDIT*

The [aforementioned blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/34709581001/lets-not) makes for some interesting reading.

Comment: I just rewrote one of my model tests to avoid it, and it's actually quite a bit more clear. The request/integration tests seems to be a bit harder to rewrite, so I may not be too strict, but overall I'm liking the approach of just using helper methods instead of the let/before/subject. I'm eager to see their blog post as well before I just dive in and rewrite all of my tests :-)