# RSpec + Sidekiq: NoMethodError: undefined method 'jobs' MyImportJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I am trying to write some specs for RSpec + Sidekiq in a Rails 4.2.4 app, but am encountering some issues.

My code looks like this:

```
class MyImportJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :default

  def perform(params)
    # Do magic
  end
end
```

and the spec:

```
describe MyImportJob, type: :job do
  let(:panel) { create(:panel) }

  describe '#perform' do
    context 'unsuccessfully' do
      it 'raises ArgumentError if no panel param was passed' do
        expect {subject.perform_async()}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
      end
    end

    context 'successfully' do
      it 'given a panel, it increases the job number' do
        expect {
          subject.perform_async(panel_id: panel.id)
        }.to change(subject.jobs, :size).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I am receiving the following errors:

```
Failure/Error: }.to change(subject.jobs, :size).by(1)
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `jobs' for #<MyImportJob:0x007f80b74c5c18>
```

and

```
Failure/Error: expect {subject.perform_async()}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  expected ArgumentError, got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `perform_async' for #<MyImportJob:0x007f80b6d73f50>>
```

I believe `perform_async` should be provided by default by Sidekiq as long as I include the line `include Sidekiq::Worker` in my worker, is this correct? The first test passes if I just use `perform` but I'd expect it to pass with `perform_async` which is what I'm using in my codebase.

As for the second, I don't understand why there is no method `jobs` for the test subject. Any clue about that?

My `rails_helper.rb` file has:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sidenote: the  tests in this question are rather useless. You're testing functionality of sidekiq (duplicating the effort). It's quite safe to assume that sidekiq "just works", so your tests should check your actual logic ("check that welcome email is scheduled if and only if a valid signup form was posted")

Comment: Yep that is the next step, I was just wondering how I could get the basic tests to even work. Now I know that it's `subject`s fault. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yep, baby steps. Just making sure. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you don't define `subject` explicitly, rspec will create subject as following rule:

> By default, if the first argument to an outermost example group
>   (describe or context block) is a class, RSpec creates an instance of
>   that class and assigns it to the subject

ref: [What's the difference between RSpec's subject and let? When should they be used or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437162/whats-the-difference-between-rspecs-subject-and-let-when-should-they-be-used)

That means it create instance of your worker. So that you can't call `perform_async` and `jobs`.

To resolve your issue, define it explicitly as below:

```
describe MyImportJob, type: :job do
  let(:panel) { create(:panel) }

  subject { MyImportJob }

  describe '#perform' do
    context 'unsuccessfully' do
      it 'raises ArgumentError if no panel param was passed' do
        expect {subject.perform_async()}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
      end
    end

    context 'successfully' do
      it 'given a panel, it increases the job number' do
        expect {
          subject.perform_async(panel_id: panel.id)
        }.to change(subject.jobs, :size).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> expected ArgumentError, got `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'perform_async' for #<MyImportJob:0x007f80b6d73f50>>`

`perform_async` is a method on worker class itself.

```
MyImportJob.perform_async(...)
```

> I don't understand why there is no method `jobs` for the test subject

The same exact reason. It's a method on the worker class.

Comment: subject is `MyImportJob` so it should be correct. Same behavior if I pass in the class name

Comment: @DaniG2k: Is it, though? How do you know? (error message says otherwise)

Comment: Gah! You are right...I checked what `subject` was with `binding.pry` and thought it was `MyImportJob`