# why does Rspec increment return of called application

Tags: json, ruby, loops, rspec

I have an RSpec test currently written on an application that 100% works, it current returns exactly what I want.

The application call method returns a Json list and the test I have is then supposed to check if certain elements are equal to an equivalent Json passed in. Simple right?

```
describe App do
   subject(:jsonlist) do
   final_json = App.call(json)
   JSON.load(final_json)
end

it "checks the json" do
  expect(jsonlist[2]["num"].to eq "10.00")
end
```

It works fine for one test. But after that, Rspec calls the application again and again, adding the data on top of the existing json elements (10 becomes 20, 30, 160 whatever).

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening and how I can get Rspec to stop calling the application when I only need it to call the returned data once?

Many thanks in advance. My apologies for any confusion, I'm still new here

Comment: The indentation here looks mangled. Is that all inside `describe` or not?

Comment: The `subject` declaration might be the issue here as those are [a little weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437162/whats-the-difference-between-rspecs-subject-and-let-when-should-they-be-used).

Comment: @tadman Apologies, yes ```describe App``` is inside an ```RSpec.describe``` at the top of the test. Though this section appears to be where the issue is originating

Comment: Does `App` preserve state somehow? It's hard to tell from this limited example.

Comment: @tadman ```App``` just returns an array of hashes converted into JSON from data passed in via the argument so doesn't maintain anything. It appears Rspec is memorising the returned output somehow when running the subject tests

Comment: Just noticed that `expect(jsonlist[2]["num"].to eq "10.00")` should be `expect(jsonlist[2]["num"]).to eq "10.00"`.

Comment: You may want to compare the whole document, like `expect(jsonlist).to eq([ ... ])` with the expected content.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It's still not clear how this is structured. The `subject ... do` block implies there's additional content.

Comment: @tadman thanks heaps! I think that was just a typo. I agree with you in that I think ```subject``` is to blame here

Comment: A) Try `let`. B) Fix synax!

Comment: I'm wondering if there are more than one test checking fields in the JSON? If so, each test would call subject all over again. So, if you have 10 tests, the app would be called 10 times. Posting more of the spec file would help me help you.